# Why NULL values when importing XML to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xml

I've got an XML file roughly in this format:

```
 <stuff thing="value" thing2="1435158141" version2="1.0-BETA" version2="1.03">
    <info type="A" protocol="tcp"/>
    <host id="14444158141">
        <address addr="1.2.3.4" addrtype="ipv4"/>
        <ports>
            <port protocol="tcp" portid="80">
                <state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64"/>
            </port>
        </ports>
    </host>
    <runstats>
    <finished time="1435158153" timestr="2015-06-24 11:02:33" elapsed="12"/>
    <things up="15838" down="0" total="15838"/>
    </runstats>
 </stuff>
```

I want a MySQL table with the addr, addrtype, protocol, and portid data in it. So I create a database in MySQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
`addr` varchar(255),
`addrtype` varchar(255),
`protocol` varchar(255),
`portid` varchar(255)
);
```

Then I import the XML file into MySQL like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE stuff 
ROWS IDENTIFIED by '<host>';
```

However, only the protocol and portid columns are populated. The addr and addrtype columns are not and show NULL. Why?

MySQL version is 5.5.43 on Ubuntu 14.10.1.

Comment: Your XML doesn't match any of the formats shown in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html. You're lucky it loaded anything.